# Webkit.net and own javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, webkit, textinput

Well, the question is very simple.

I've got an webkit browser in an class file generated this way:

```
public static WebKit.WebKitBrowser mainBrowser = new WebKitBrowser();
```

Now I'm trying to login on an website automaticly. But the input fields aren't filled in.

I'm using this code to get to the point where the data needs to be filled in:

```
public void loginthen()
{
    this.Controls.Add(globalVars.mainBrowser);
    globalVars.mainBrowser.DocumentCompleted += 
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(mainBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
    globalVars.mainBrowser.Navigate("http://www.somesite.com/");                
}

void mainBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var send = sender as WebKit.WebKitBrowser;
    if (send.Url == e.Url)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Inloggen");
        globalVars.mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("user").TextContent = "User Name";
    }
}
```

The `MessageBox` is shown, and i get no error, but the input field isn't filled in.

The HTML of the input fields is this:

```
<input id="user" name="user" class="text" type="text" value="" onkeydown="if((e=window.event||event) &amp;&amp; e.keyCode == 13 &amp;&amp; $('#user').val() &amp;&amp; $('#password').val()) $('#login_button').trigger('click');">
```

So my thought was... Am I using the `TextContent` wrong?

And can this (and triggering the button and so on) not be much easier be done with javascript?

So I googled and searched for it, but the only thing that I can find is how to call C# function from javascript or how to call an javascript function from C#. But I don't own these sites, so that won't work...

So what are your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
globalVars.mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("user").TextContent = "User Name";
```

you should use:

```
globalVars.mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("user").SetAttribute("value", "User Name");
```

You may use the `TextContent` property to set the content of a HTML tag such as `<p />`, `<span />` or maybe `<div />`.

```
globalVars.mainBrowser.Document.GetElementById("myDiv").TextContent = "some div content";
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. It's working now. Thank you. Marked your answer as THE answerm but must wait 16 hours to give you the bounty... Thanks again